# how to fetch the data in JSP inside table based on drop down selection

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have three tables 
1. Employee details
2. Customer Details
3. Billing Details

In create Bill page there will Employeeid dropdown box based on that selection employeename should come in the next box... similar for Customer also
 additionally Billing start date and End date + Billing amounts box will be there..

Actual Question 
1. Employee name and customer name is not auto populating in the box when Id is 
selected
2. WHen user click on Submit EMPid,cutomerid,billingstart date, end date and billing amount also not taking..

```
String sql="insert into    billingdetail(ID,billingstartdate,billingenddate
,billingamount,customerid) values('"+ID+"','"+billingstartdate+"','"+billingenddate+"','"
+billingamount+"','"+customerid+"')";
```

Employee_Details

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbb"
,"root","gm@i‌​l@123"); 
Statement st=con.createStatement(); 
String sql=("SELECT id,name,design,statuss,jobfamilyy,jobtitlee,billablee FROM infoo"); 
String sql1=("SELECT customerid,customername FROM customerdetail");  
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

JSP

```
<div style="width:200px; float:left;"> 
    <select name="customerid" onchange="showCustomer1(this.value)"> 
       <option VALUE="blank" SELECTED>Please Select 
           <% while (rs2.next()) 
             {%> <option VALUE="<%=rs2.getString(1)%>">
                <%=rs2.getString(1)%> <%}%> 
    </select> </div></div> 
    <% String customerid=request.getParameter("customerid"); 
        ResultSet rs5=st.executeQuery("SELECT customername FROM 
         customerdetail where customerid="+ customerid +""); 
     <% while(rs5.next()) { %> 
        <tr><td><%=rs5.getString(1)%></td></tr> 
     <%}%>
```

Comment: Dear chethan, Show me your code and tell me what you have tried or any error or exception coming.

Comment: code to fetach Employee detail:
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbb","root","gm@il@123");
 
Statement st=con.createStatement();

String sql=("SELECT id,name,design,statuss,jobfamilyy,jobtitlee,billablee FROM infoo");
String sql1=("SELECT customerid,customername FROM customerdetail");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

Comment: This is not a way to share your code. It creates more complexity to understand or find the bug. I think, you are beginner on stackoverflow. Just update your question and add proper coding with explanation in which you are getting error to get better answer from us. Thanks

Comment: code to fetch customer details
 Customer_ID   :    
  <div style="width:200px; float:left;">
    <select name="customerid" onchange="showCustomer1(this.value)">
<option VALUE="blank" SELECTED>Please Select
<%            while (rs2.next()) {%>
                      <option VALUE="<%=rs2.getString(1)%>"><%=rs2.getString(1)%>
<%}%>
  </select> </div></div> 
  <%
  String customerid=request.getParameter("customerid");
 ResultSet rs5=st.executeQuery("SELECT customername FROM customerdetail where customerid="+ customerid +"");
<%
while(rs5.next())
{ %>
 <tr><td><%=rs5.getString(1)%></td></tr>
<%}%>

Comment: Chethan - I have posted complete example based on your problem. Just execute this program in system and I assure, you will be agreed. Let me know if you still get any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I create a complete example for solving your problem. You haven't specify clearly where you are getting error and it's little bit difficult to understand your code.

Just try to execute this program, I assure it will surely solve your problem and give you better understanding in JSP, Servlet and DBCode also.

When you run this program.

Two drop down in JSP page.

1 -  for display all states (default dynamic value retrieve from database)

2 - for display cities when you select any state.

When you select any state, city will be display on city combo box and after refreshing page selected state position will also stable in state combo.

As well as when you select state, I displayed a records from different table in tabular format or can say using table,tr,td tags.

Three tables in database - States, city, data

States - to display all states default in state combo when you run example.
City - when you select state then city will come based on selected state.
data - when you select state data will show in tabular form (Just retrieved all data instead of based from anything).

Files - JSP (Client, Server side code), Servlet (Server side code), DBCoding (Database code)

IDE - MyEclipse
Database - MS SQL 2012

JSP Coding

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*,DBCode.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="<%=basePath%>">

    <title>My JSP 'MyJsp.jsp' starting page</title>

    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">    
    <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3">
    <meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my page">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function abc()
    {
        document.forms["formname"].submit();
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <%

  DBCoding db = new DBCoding();
  ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
  al = db.RetrieveStateName();
  String value1="";
   %>
  <body>
  <form action="Servlet1" method="post" name="formname" id="formname">
    <select id="selectvalue" name="selectvalue" onchange="abc()";>

    <%if(request.getParameter("abc")!=null)
    {
    String result = request.getParameter("abc");
    %>
        <%for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++)
        {
            if(al.get(i).equals(result))
            {%>
            <option value= "<%=al.get(i) %>" selected="selected"><%=al.get(i) %></option>
            <%}
            else
            {%>

            <option value= "<%=al.get(i) %>"><%=al.get(i) %></option>
            <%} %>
        <%}%>
    <%}
    else
    { %>

    <%for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++)
    {
     %>
    <option value= "<%=al.get(i) %>"><%=al.get(i) %></option>
    <%} %>

    <%} %>

    </select>

    <%ArrayList ob = new ArrayList(); %>
    <%if(request.getAttribute("City_Name")!=null)
    {
        ob = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("City_Name");
        %>
        <select id="selectcity" name="selectcity">
        <%for(int j=0;j<ob.size();j++)
        {
        %>
            <option><%=ob.get(j)%></option>
       <%} %>
        </select><br/><br/>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <%
              DBCoding db2 = new DBCoding();
              ArrayList al2 = new ArrayList();
              ResultSet rs = db2.getTable();
              while(rs.next()){
              %>
              <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString(1) %></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(3) %></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(4) %></td>
            </tr>
               <%
               } %>
    <%} 
    else
    {

    %>
        <select>
        <option></option>
        </select>
    <%} %>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Servlet coding

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import DBCode.DBCoding;


public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Constructor of the object.
     */
    public Servlet1() {
        super();
    }

    public void destroy() {
        super.destroy(); 
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String getstatename = request.getParameter("selectvalue");

        DBCoding ob = new DBCoding();
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al = ob.RetrieveCityName(getstatename);

        request.setAttribute("City_Name", al);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("MyJsp.jsp?abc="+getstatename);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // Put your code here
    }

}
```

DBCoding - Database code

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DBCoding
{
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    int result=0;
    public DBCoding()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:SearchAccount");
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {}
    }
    public ArrayList RetrieveStateName()
    {
        ArrayList ob = new ArrayList();
        try
        {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("select distinct states from States");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            ob.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {}
        return ob;
    }
    public ArrayList RetrieveCityName(String statename)
    {
        ArrayList ob = new ArrayList();
        try
        {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("select city from city where statename=?");
        ps.setString(1,statename);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            ob.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {}
        return ob;
    }

    public ResultSet getTable()
    {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try
        {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from data");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {}
        return rs; 
    }
}
```

After executing this example, if you get any query, just drop me a message and I will sort it out surely.