# Implementing a parent child table in Jsp and servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have displayed departments in a table inside a `jsp` page. Now i want when user selects some department from departments table, all the employee from that department become available to view in a second table. Can that be done in J2EE ? please share something useful.

Comment: Is not clear what how you want to do this. Seems that can be a directly style, like that is presented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31675740/how-to-fetch-the-data-in-jsp-inside-table-based-on-drop-down-selection. On other hand you can use your jsp page just for view layer.

Comment: That's very long to cover in this site. Go check for a tutorial or something. Seriously, your question seems like *please do my work for me*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that's not what i am asking for. haven't found anything good on web. can you share some links or tutorials

Comment: what you are looking for is something called ajax , check the following link as an introduction to ajax http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is to display the department employees in the second table. 
My assumptions are:

- The second table is in the same page as the first table containing departments
- You want to do this dynamically, w/o refreshing the page

(Let me know if my assumptions are incorrect)

(assuming they are correct) What you are really looking for is an AJAX implementation, and there are plenty ways to do it (whether you have a framework or just simple JSP/servlet). Research on it.